# $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} f_n(x) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_{n}$ is a sequence of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ f_{n} (x) = \frac{1}{x} \qquad \text{ if } \qquad x \in (n,n+1)$$

and $0$ otherwise.

Is it true that

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f_{n} = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f $$

where $f$ is the limit function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The pointwise limit of the sequence is $0$, and

$$\int_{(0,\infty)}f_n(x)dx=\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}$$

which you can evaluate directly with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Can i apply bounded,monotone or dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @nonlinear : why would you want to?  The sequence is not monotone. The least upper bound of $(|f_n|)$ is not integrable.  I'm not familiar with the ``bounded'' one.